# Fill and Border color property of data point marker (scatter or line) Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, colors, charts, marker

I am writing some code to loop through each data point in a chart and change the color (fill/border) of the point marker if it is the wrong color. I don't want it to change if it is a compliant color (using a select case).

Problem: Checking markerbackgroundcolor and markerforegroundcolor returns "-1" no matter what the color is until i manually change the color (right click marker and change fill from automatic to solid).Something to do with Automatic colors.

Basic example in immediate window (after inserted scatter chart without changing formatting):

```
?Activechart.SeriesCollection(1).points(1).markerbackgroundcolor
returns 
-1
```

Then without doing anything else:

```
Activechart.SeriesCollection(2).points(1).markerbackgroundcolor=255
?Activechart.SeriesCollection(2).points(1).markerbackgroundcolor
 255
```

Is there another property of the marker I can test instead? Or another approach entirely? The checking of the color itself is critical to other parts of the code so all the work arounds I've tried so far are not cutting it : (

PS new user, apologies if haven't formulated question too well.

Comment: This from 2005:  http://www.office-archive.com/33-excel/57ab74e17cab9710.htm  It may be that nothing has changed since then, and it's not really possible to do what you want in an easy way.  There may be some other approach you can take which avoids having to read the current color though, depending on exactly why you need to reformat your points.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can change individual data points (or, at least I don't know how).  I think that the problem lies in checking for "compliant colors."  This type of color property seems to require a Long value which corresponds to a color.

This code worked for me (Excel 2007) on a line-chart in chart I created for a project (I added the `Debug.Print` lines to show the numbers returned for Series in my chart)...

```
Sub formatTable()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim co As ChartObject
    Dim c As Integer

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set co = ws.ChartObjects("Chart1")

    With co.Chart
        Debug.Print .Name
        For c = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
            Debug.Print .SeriesCollection(c).Name
            Debug.Print "Foreground Color: " & .SeriesCollection(c).MarkerForegroundColorIndex    'Get Forground Color
            Debug.Print "Background Color: " & .SeriesCollection(c).MarkerBackgroundColorIndex    ' Get Background color
            .SeriesCollection(c).MarkerForegroundColorIndex = 5 'Set foreground to Blue
            .SeriesCollection(c).MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = 42    ' Set background to Lt Blue
        Next c
    End With
End Sub
```

After re-reading your question, I dug a little deeper to see how to check or set the color for a `Point`.  All you should need to do is embed another `FOR` loop inside of the above code. The important thing in this line is to use:  `.SeriesCollection(c).Points.Item(i).Marker... = Value`

Comment: Thank you! The coloring of the points works fine, but the Foreground Color lines debug print "2" as the Foreground and background colors for each series, even though one series is the Excel default blue and the other default red: ChartSheet1 Chart 1
Series1
Foreground Color: 2
Background Color: 2
Series2
Foreground Color: 2
Background Color: 2